# Conditional Iteration Over w:r siblings

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

```
I have the following piece of xml:
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> ADDIN EN.CITE &lt;EndNote&gt;&lt;Cite&gt;&lt;Author&gt;Su&lt;/Author&gt;&lt;Year&gt;2010&lt;/Year&gt;&lt;RecNum&gt;130&lt;/RecNum&gt;toethanol/metabolism&lt;/keyword&gt;&lt;keyword&gt;Molecular Sequence Data&lt;/keyword&gt;&lt;keyword&gt;Mutagenesis, Insertional&lt;/keyword&gt;&lt;keyword&gt;Sequence Alignment&lt;/keyword&gt;&lt;keyword&gt;/genetics/*metabolism&lt;/keyword&gt;&lt;/keywords&gt;&lt;dates&gt;&lt/EndNote&gt;</w:instrText>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>(ABCD et al. 2006)</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
            </w:r>
         </w:p>
```

What I want to do is , search for `w:fldChar` with value `"begin"` , and if found , move a level up to `w:r` and search for `w:instrText` which should contain the text "`ADDIN EN.CITE`" and if it does , go one level up to w:r again and extract the text contained in `w:t` tag that follows next..

I tried the following but it yields nothing:

```
text = ""
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
for p in source.xpath('.//w:p',namespaces={'w':w}):
        text+= " "
        for q in p.xpath('.//w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType="begin"]',namespaces={'w':w}): #search for w:fldchar
            for t in q.xpath('/../..//w:instrText[contains(text(),"ADDIN EN.CITE")]/..//w:r',namespaces={'w':w}):  #check for addin en cite
               for r in t.itersiblings(tag = '{'+w+'}r'): #iterate over siblings of w:r
                   if r.xpath('.//w:t',namespaces={'w':w}): #if w:t in the sibling , extract text and break..
                       text+= r.text
                       break
```

What is going wrong ?? Problem seems with the q.xpath statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't very hard but required some research. After searching around I could extract the text by using:

```
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
for p in source.xpath('.//w:p//w:instrText[contains(text(),"ADDIN EN.CITE")]',namespaces={'w':w}):
    text+= " "
    for q in p.xpath('../following-sibling::w:r//w:t',namespaces = {'w':w}):
        text+= q.text
        break
```

This works well. following sibling iterates over the various run instances at the same level. Since the text is contained in the 4th run instance , I broke out of the loop once I got the text.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the XPath expression in

```
 for t in q.xpath('/../..//w:instrText...'...)
```

doesn't make sense. The initial `/` means "start from the root node" (i.e. the parent of the outermost element). The following step, `..`, means "the parent of the context node". But the root node doesn't have a parent. So this expression will select nothing. (In fact, in XPath 1.0, `/..` is used as a convenient way to specify an empty node-set.)

Instead you probably want

```
 for t in q.xpath('../..//w:instrText...'...)
```

which starts by taking the parent of the context node (the value of `t`).

So that will fix one fatal problem. I'm not sure whether your XPaths are correct otherwise, because I had trouble following your description of what they were supposed to do.

Comment: I want to extract text in the 3rd w:r tag. but before that I need to check whether the 2nd run tag has w:instrtext with the text addin en cite. If it has , then extract the text, otherwise no..

Comment: how about using "following-sibling" instead ?? as in the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) . I am still facing problems with it.. just need to extract first text under any sibling and then break..

Comment: @Swordy: your requirements are still not clear. In your original question, you say you want to extract the text from a w:t element. But here you say you want to extract text in the 3rd w:r element, which has no w:t child. I'm confused.

Comment: _The fourth r element contains a t element that holds the result of the field's processing (or the initial value for the field)._ sorry for the confusion..

Comment: The text will always be in the 4th w:r element.. @LarsH